# Print the image in PDF in C#.net window application

Tags: c#, pdf, desktop-application

**I want the code for Print the image in pdf**.I am having one **image** and one **"Print" button** in my form. When i click on that print then image should print in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) pretty heavily and had pretty good luck with it. I would start there and the documentation should allow you to get to your goal pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with the open-source iTextSharp, which can easily add images to PDF files.  Here is an article from Mike's DotNetting: [iTextSharp - Working With Images](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images)